# Why is this question related to conditional probability?

Tags: probability

**The question is : On an island, 1/3 of the natives always lie, and 2/3 of the natives always tell the truth.  You reach a fork in the road, and go to a pair of natives standing nearby to ask for directions.  The first one says to go left. The second person says, “yes, that’s right, he’s telling the truth.”  What is the probability that you should follow the directions**

My attempt is by first thinking about in what kind of situations the statement in the question would work out:

There are 4 possibilities TT, FF, FT, TF of these 4 possibilities I deduce that only TT and FF can validate the statement in the question.

In the case of FT if the first person tells lie by lying that the correct way is on the left then the second person who always speaks truth will undoubtedly contradict with what first said.

Similarly, the TF case doesn't stand either because if the first person tells the truth, the second person who always lies will contradict with what the first person said.

Thus, the probability that you should follow the direction would be the probability that both natives are telling the truth which is $\frac {2}{3} * \frac {2}{3}$. However, the solution given for this question is $\frac {4}{5}$ how could this be??

Comment: If the only possibilities are FF and TT and you say the TT case has probability $\frac{4}{9}$, presumably you would say that the FF case has probability $\frac{1}{9}$ or at least it's lower than the FF case, but then where did the other $\frac{4}{9}$ of probability go?

Comment: You've treated the answers given by the natives as random...but they're not. Certain natives always tell the truth, etc.; what's random is the first person you talk to. That person could be a liar or a truthteller. A hidden assumption is that the two natives you encounter both have probability 1/3 of being liars and 2/3 of being truth-tellers, and that these probabilities are independent. These assumptions are not necessarily correct, but to get an answer, you need to assume so.

Comment: To see they're not necessarily correct, imagine that (a) there's a law saying liars have to stay indoors at all times, or (b) there's a tradition that liars always choose liars as their travelling companions, and the same for truth-tellers. In the first case, the first assumption is violated; in the second, the "independence" assumption is violated. But either (or both) are consistent with the data you've been given. In short: it's a lousy problem, but with pretty reasonable assumptions about what the asker intended, you can answer it. You need the right probability space, though.

Comment: @DerekElkins the other $\frac {4}{9}$ concerns the FT or TF cases no?

Comment: @JohnHughes I think for sure I was missing something, because this problem can't be this easy. I did assume that the two events being independent though I'm not sure what other sample space I"m missing besides the TT, FF, TF, FT cases

Comment: @pino231 You've (correctly) argued that the TF and FT cases are impossible. Clearly, if something is impossible, it can't happen four times out of nine. So those cases must have probability $0$. The remaining cases' probabilities must sum to $1$ since for sure one or the other is the case.

Comment: @DerekElkins I see what you're saying now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we are **given** their responses, we know that we are restricted to two possibilities like you deduced: either they both are telling the truth or both are lying.

Assuming the chances of someone always lying or always telling the truth are independent, we have probability of two people always telling the truth to be $(2/3)^2 = 4/9$ Likewise, the probability of two people both lying is $1/9$. The probability that either of these two possibilities happen is $4/9 + 1/9 = 5/9$. This is the event that we are conditioning on:

> The probability that both are telling the truth **given** that their responses were "go left" and "person 1 is telling the truth".

Therefore the probability that their directions are correct is $$\frac{4/9}{5/9} = \frac45$$

If we were not given what their responses were, your answer would be correct because we would have nothing to condition on.

Comment: sorry this might seem like a silly question but what phrasing in the question suggested the "given " part? For instance, when I'm working on other probability question when I see the wording something something GIVEN something I know immediately in those cases to use conditional probability. However, in question like this one it's not immediately clear to me why conditional probability is involved.

Comment: It's because of all four possibilities (TT, TF, FT, FF), two of those possibilities are not possible and end up as a contradiction like you pointed out. So our sample space has been conditioned, thus means we are dealing with conditional probability

Comment: ah I think I kind of get it now, it's like drawing cards without replacement the sample size is reduced thus it's "conditioned"

Answer (score 2):

As TF and FT are impossible, you need to calculate:
$$P(TT|TT\cup FF)=\frac{P(TT)}{P(TT\cup FF)}=\frac{\frac{4}{9}}{\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{9}}=\frac{4}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you, looking at the setup you have I know I missed the sample space